# In C++, using GDAL library, calculate distance in meters between two points

Tags: c++, distance, gdal, points

I'm coding in C++, using GDAL library, with WGS84. How do you calculate distance between two points in meters?  The code snippet below returns a value of 1.0000.

```
OGRSpatialReference  wgs84;
OGRPoint         point1,
             point2;

assert(wgs84.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")==OGRERR_NONE);
point1.assignSpatialReference(&wgs84);
point2.assignSpatialReference(&wgs84);
point1.setY(25.0000); point1.setX(75.0000);
point2.setY(25.0000); point2.setX(76.0000);
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?  It seems that there is only one meter between 75 and 76 meters, no ?

Comment: I'm using WGS84 - which is latitude and longitude.  So, that's 25N / 75E and 25N 76E.

Comment: The algorithm to compute this is the Vincenty formula.  You can also use the Haversine.  GDAL does not provide this.  If the coordinates are close enough that a projected coordinate system works, then you can just convert them both to the same UTM grid and compute the distance using the distance formula.  The is only recommended though if you pick the right grid and the points are close.  1 degree of latitude may be stretching it for a projected coordinate system.

Comment: Here is a code snippet I wrote a while ago. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/using-gdal-c-to-calculate-distance-in-meters/144114#144114